# Can you catch me?

Tags: riddle, word

1. Part of me is surrounded by water.
2. Part of me, when away, is missed a lot.
3. Part of me is used in a western European language as a first name.
4. Part of me can make you move and tremble.

**What am I?**

Hint 1:

> I am a nine-letter word.

Hint 2:

> I am a rarity since COVID-19.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To revisit this one almost two years later, I think the answer should be:

> **HANDSHAKE**

*1. Part of me is surrounded by water.*

> A **[HAKE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hake)** is a fish, which in its natural habitat (i.e. the ocean) is always *surrounded by water*.

*2. Part of me, when away, is missed a lot.*

> When somebody has a very "**HANDS**-off" (hands-*away*) approach to something, they tend not to be too present or involved, and thus might be '*missed a lot*'.

*3. Part of me is used in a western European language as a first name.*

> **[HAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_(given_name))** is a common name in Dutch, being the short form of Johannes or Hendrik.

*4. Part of me can make you move and tremble.*

> If you **SHAKE** somebody, you make them *move and tremble*!

Altogether (with overlap), we have:

> HAN + HANDS + SHAKE + HAKE, giving us **HANDSHAKE** - an action performed by *catching* another person by the hand (hence the title too).

And re the hints:

> 'Handshake' is indeed a 9-letter word and an action now often actively avoided in the age of COVID-19 (to avoid potential disease transmission).

Answer (score 7):

You are:

> [Leonardo DiCaprio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo_DiCaprio)

1. Part of me is surrounded by water.

> [**CAPRI**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capri) is an island

2. Part of me, when away, is missed a lot.

> [Lady **DI**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diana,_Princess_of_Wales) is missed a lot since her death in 1997

3. Part of me is used in a western European language as a first name.

> [**LEONARDO**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo) of course

4. Part of me can make you move and tremble.

> The [**RIO** carnival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rio_Carnival)

Can you catch me?

> [I wish I could](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch_Me_If_You_Can)

Comment: +1 I think this is it.

Comment: Nice answer, it fits all the clues! But this puzzle is in need of improvement if this is right.

Comment: Υou  are funny, but this is not  the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

My answer:

> Earthquake

1. Part of me is surrounded by water.

> Earth is surrounded by water

2. Part of me, when away, is missed a lot.

> This could be art, or qu - the abbreviation for queen.

3. Part of me is used in a western European language as a first name.

> [Åke is a masculine Swedish given name](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiZ66jJpO_tAhWkiOAKHWiKDd0QFjAEegQIBxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%25C3%2585ke&usg=AOvVaw2bjV-_mseY81uoRmikHwuA) Sweden is mostly considered a Western European country due to its prominent affluence and its lack of similarity with Eastern European countries.

4. Part of me can make you move and tremble.

> That's what an earthquake does.

Comment: Nice try, but not the correct answer.